# Conceito: Melhor modelo de banco de dados para conjugação verbal

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

## Contexto

Quero criar uma API para retornar informações de verbos conjugados (modo, pessoa, tempo e o infinitivo)

Em termos práticos, eu forneço um verbo **conjugado** como parâmetro na rota, por exemplo: `http://conjugar-verbo.com.br/api/sentou` e a api retorna o modo, o tempo, a pessoa e o infinitivo do verbo. assim:

```js
{
  modo: 'indicativo'
  tempo: 'pretérito perfeito'
  pessoa: 'terceira do singular'
  infinitivo: 'sentar'
}
```

O banco de dados teria uns 80 verbos. caso o verbo não constasse no banco, o JSON retornaria uma mensagem

```
{
  mensagem: 'esse verbo não consta na lista'
}
```

### Uma questão conceitual:

## Qual seria o melhor modelo de banco de dados para conjugação de verbos?

Primeiro, o que significa melhor

- melhor performance na consulta
- query mais simples

Hoje eu faço um *web scraping* no site `https://www.conjugacao.com.br/` como pode ser conferido aqui o resultado: https://app-scriba-pro.herokuapp.com/api/conjuga_verbo/sentou

Dentro de uma aplicação que eu fiz, eu usei essa técnica de *web scraping*, mas ele está demorando um pouco (dentro da aplicação), por isso pensei em melhorar a performance com um database meu.

## O que eu fiz como modelo do banco de dados

Segue um ER bem auto-explicativo: separando por modo, por tempo, com colunas das pessoas e claro, um FK para a tabela 'verbo'. Assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou, uma alternativa, seria uma única tabela com 72 colunas como:
`'indicativo_presente_eu' 'indicativo_presente_tu' 'indicativo_presente_ele' etc...`

Confesso que eu ainda não sei fazer consulta com JOIN (ainda estou começando com database) portanto não sei ao certo o que seria mais performático, ou a diferença é irrisória, ou mesmo como fazer a query.

Por isso essa questão conceitual:

## Qual o melhor modelo de banco de dados para conjugação de verbos?

Comment: Se entendi bem, o melhor banco é o relacional mesmo, só precisa mudar a modelagem. Ao criar tabelas como "presente do indicativo" e colunas como "eu", "tu", "eles", você perde a oportunidade de consultar essas informações de maneira simples no banco através de condições do `where` e _joins_ baseados em chaves estrangeiras. Não vou detalhar aqui uma modelagem mais apropriada, cabem perguntas separadas. Para fins de utilidade para o site, esta pergunta é muito específica e só atende o seu caso, e nem precisa envolver especificamente o domíno de conjugação de verbos, é uma dúvida sobre modelagem.

Comment: Mas pense em algo assim ("acho" quer seria mais ou menos assim, não lembro bem os conceitos gramaticais): `select verbos.forma_verbal from verbos inner join infinitivos on verbo.id_infinivo = infinitivos.id inner join tempos_verbais on verbos.id_tempo_verbal = tempos_verbais.id inner join pessoas_verbais on verbos.pessoa_verbal = pessoas_verbais.id where infinitivos.nome = 'buscar' and tempos_verbais.nome = 'presente do indicativo' and pessoas_verbais.nome = 'eu';`.

Comment: Em geral considero benéfico estudar sobre bancos de dados relacionais em geral, chaves estrangeiras, modelagem relacional e normalização (formas normais em bancos relacionais).

Comment: De fato é uma questão de modelagem. eu só trouxe essa questão por conjugação de verbos porque o material que estou revisando lida com objetos como classes de representação do mundo real e seus atributos (como carros e numero de portas). Mas qdo eu levei isso para 'verbos' me deu um branco do tipo peraí, o que seriam atributos dos verbos? seus tempos verbais, modos e pessoas ou as combinações de cada um... a conjugação em um todo... foi aí que me voltei para a modelagem de abstrações (e não objetos concretos e suas relações) como conjugar verbos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Acredito que encontrei a melhor forma de modelar. Vou deixar postado para consulta.*

O problema era que os verbos conjugados estão no mesmo domínio, ou seja, conjugação. Portanto deveriam estar na mesma coluna. O que facilita a consulta, por exemplo `SELECT * FROM conjugado WHERE verbo_conjugado LIKE 'cantou'`

As demais colunas apresentam as combinações de `modo`, `tempo`, `pessoa` e `forma nominal`. Portanto a tabela de `conjugados` ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o diagrama ER ficaria assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo que as tabelas `modo`, `tempo` e `pessoa` tenham pouquissimos registros e que não mudam, o uso de FK diminui o erro de preenchimento (consistencia do banco)

E para inserir um novo verbo, basta inclui-lo na tabela `formas nominais` com 'infinitivo', ''gerundio' e 'participio' e depois conjuga-lo na tabela `conjugado`